# Select xml nodes that have dot in the name using XPath

Tags: sql-server, xpath

I am trying to select text nodes of Lookup.Result element of the following xml document using XPath in Sql Server.

```
<Commands>
<Command id="1">
<Lookup.Result>Result.OK</Lookup.Result>
</Command>
</Commands>
```

I try the following query:

```
declare @xml xml
set @xml = '<Commands>
    <Command id="1">
    <Lookup.Result>Result.OK</Lookup.Result>
    </Command>
    </Commands>
'
select t.c.value('./Lookup&#46;Result/text()[1]', 'varchar(20)')
from @xml.nodes('/Commands/Command') t(c)
```

but i get the following error:
XQuery [value()]: Syntax error near 'Lookup'

How can I escape . (dot in Lookup.Result element tag name) in an XPath expression?
Please, help find an elegant solution to this problem.
Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    declare @xml xml 
    set @xml = '<Commands>
    <Command id="1">
    <Lookup.Result>Result.OK</Lookup.Result>
    </Command>
    </Commands> ' 

    select t.c.value('(./Lookup.Result/text())[1]', 'varchar(20)') 
    from @xml.nodes('/Commands/Command') t(c)
```

you are missing the

> ()

around the xpath above, MSSQL handles the . fine on my machine

Comment: You are right. There are so many combinations when debugging, that I ommited parentheses in one of them...:)) It works now. It may seem that a dot is always interpreted as the current node, but it seems that in some situations it is considered just a text. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are only 5 escape chars:

```
"   &quot;
'   &apos;
<   &lt;
>   &gt;
&   &amp;
```

so you need a function to preprocess then and another to post process. i.e. wrap 5 nested REPLACE statements in a udf...